# Passport.js Execution

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js, passport-local

I have been looking at some `passport.js` tutorials online but haven't grasped a clear understanding of what is happening. Can someone help me clear my doubts below? **Please read the paragraph at the bottom first.**

So assuming I set up everything correctly, this is the login strategy:

```
passport.use('login', new LocalStrategy({
    passReqToCallback : true
  },
  function(req, username, password, done) { 
    // check in mongo if a user with username exists or not
    User.findOne({ 'username' :  username }, 
      function(err, user) {
        // In case of any error, return using the done method
        if (err)
          return done(err);
        // Username does not exist, log error & redirect back
        if (!user){
          console.log('User Not Found with username '+username);
          return done(null, false, 
                req.flash('message', 'User Not found.'));                 
        }
        // User exists but wrong password, log the error 
        if (!isValidPassword(user, password)){
          console.log('Invalid Password');
          return done(null, false, 
              req.flash('message', 'Invalid Password'));
        }
        // User and password both match, return user from 
        // done method which will be treated like success
        return done(null, user);
      }
    );
}));
```

Now in my app.js (server) I have this as one of my routes:

```
/* Handle Login POST */
  router.post('/login', passport.authenticate('login', {
    successRedirect: '/home',
    failureRedirect: '/',
    failureFlash : true 
  }));
```

Now in my AJS file:

```
app.controller('loginController', function($scope) {
    var user = $resource('/login');

    $scope.createUser = function() {
        var User = new user();
        User.username = $scope.usernameVar;
        User.password = $scope.passwordVar;
        User.save();
    }
});
```

**Please read this first (Instead of going through the code first):**

So when the user clicks on the login button on the login page the `createUser` function above is run (in my AJS file). Then I create a resource object for the endpoint `'/login'` and when I call save on that it will run the route for that `'/login'` endpoint on my server (app.js). Then in my server it will `passport.authenticate('login', ...` which will run the passport middleware.

Now my question is:

In the `passport.use('login'...` strategy where the do values for the variables `req, username, and password` come from in the callback to that strategy. Do I have to explicitly pass the username and password the user enters in the textfield on my front end. Like I have a two way data binding for those two textfields in AJS view. If so how do I pass those username and password values?

Do these two lines in my AJS controller `User.username = $scope.usernameVar;` and `User.password = $scope.passwordVar;` attach the usernameVar and passwordVar values to the `req` object on my server for the route `'/login'`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a form with action to post to your path `/login`, and have input names labeled after your `username` and `password`, the submit button will pass the values along to your passport code.

Check out **Form** in the [docs](http://passportjs.org/docs/configure).

Comment: Aren't the `username` and `password` variables passed to the passport code from the req object. `"When Passport authenticates a request, it parses the credentials contained in the request. It then invokes the verify callback with those credentials as arguments, in this case username and password"`

Comment: Yes, the `username` and `password` fields are passed to the `req` object, and then passed along to passport's local strategy. See: https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-local/blob/master/lib/strategy.js#L71

Comment: Oh ok. Now it makes sense. So basically if I have `username` or `password` as the name attribute on the two textfields and it will automatically take the values of those two textfields and pass it to the request object when I click the submit button and those values for the username and password are then based to the passport code. Thanks!